# How to use python Codes in Java?

Tags: java, python

I am a beginner in Java And I have some experience in python
I am wondering if there is a way to use python in java.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd use [jython](http://www.jython.org/). You might want to look at [Py4J](https://www.py4j.org/) too.

Comment: You can run Python programs using a Java JVM with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).  You can also use Java [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) to call the Python interpreter to execute Python code from a Java program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply convert your python code to binary and use is in any other languages as a added library package. I thing Juthon comes handy in this manne.

[Jyhton documentation](http://www.jython.org/).